# Send request as content type of x-www-form-urlencoded with wreq

Tags: json, haskell, wreq

I'm learning to use wreq this weekend and I've run into some strange behavior.

I have a module `AuthRequest`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module AuthRequest where

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Monoid

data AuthRequest = AuthRequest {
    client_id :: String
  , client_secret :: String
  , grant_type :: String
} deriving (Generic,  Show)

instance ToJSON AuthRequest where
    toJSON (AuthRequest id_ secret grant) =
      object [ "client_id" .= id_
             , "client_secret" .= secret
             , "grant_type" .= grant
             ]
    toEncoding(AuthRequest id_ secret grant) =
      pairs ("client_id" .= id_ <> "client_secret" .= secret <> "grant_type" .= grant)
```

and a module `HttpDemo`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module HttpDemo where

import Control.Lens
import Network.Wreq
import AuthRequest
import Data.Aeson

clientId = "some_id"
clientSecret = "some_secret"
url = "http://localhost:5000"

opts :: Options
opts = defaults
  & header "Content-Type" .~ ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

req :: AuthRequest
req = AuthRequest clientId clientSecret "credentials"

postIt = postWith opts url (toJSON req)
```

On the other end, I have a simple python flask server that listens to this request with a breakpoint so I can see the value that comes through.

When I look at the `request.form` on the server side, I see this: `ImmutableMultiDict([('{"client_secret":"some_secret","client_id":"some_id","grant_type":"whatever"}', '')])`

The key is what should be my post body!

But if I make a similar request using the requests python library

```
requests.post('http://localhost:5000', data={'client_id': clientId, 'client_secret': clientSecret, 'grant_type': grant_type}, headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

I see what I expect: `ImmutableMultiDict([('grant_type', 'whatever'), ('client_id', 'some_id'), ('client_secret', 'some_secret')])`

What I think I want is to send this request as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I see there are some docs [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.0.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html#g:18) around this, but not clear on how to proceed. Maybe I need a FormValue instance? An example would be helpful.

Comment: If you’re sending JSON, your content type should be `application/json`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is a completely different encoding.

Comment: @AlexisKing ultimately the application I'm targeting with this request expects a urlencoded form. So maybe what I should be asking is how do I send url encoded data so it matches what python requests is sending?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the right question here. If the server expects form data, sending JSON isn’t going to work.

Answer (score 2):

As per your discussion with @Alexis, your client seems to be sending JSON, while the server is expected urlencoded. The documentation of [`Post`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.0.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html#g:4) shows how to send urlencoded data, using the [`:=`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.0.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v::-61-) constructor. In this case this would be

```
postIt = post url ["client_id" := clientId, "client_secret" := clientSecret, "grant_type" := grantType]
```

I've given the example using `post` rather than `postWith` since the default appears to be that it uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

---

There seems to be a slight complication with `OverloadedStrings`. To make a compilable program, I had to remove the AuthRequest module and explicitly give the types of the constants as below

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Network.Wreq
import Data.ByteString as B

clientId = "some_id" :: ByteString
clientSecret = "some_secret" :: ByteString
grantType = "credentials" :: ByteString
url = "http://localhost:8080"

postIt = post url ["client_id" := clientId, "client_secret" := clientSecret, "grant_type" := grantType]

main = postIt
```